# jquery select problem

Tags: jquery, select

How to find a `<input>` whose `type` is `text` and `value` is `"no"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use multiple attribute selectors:

```
$("input[type='text'][value='no']")
```

More info:

- [Selectors/attributeMultiple](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeMultiple)

Or use [`filter`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing):

```
$("input:text").filter(function () {
  return this.value == "no";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input:text[value=no]')
```